# Python: how do I pass one parameter for the string instead of having multiple repeated values?

Tags: python, string

Instead of having:

```
"my name is %s, and your name is %s" %(name, name)
```

is it possible to just have

```
"my name is %s, and your name is %s" %(name)
```

that would fill both %s with the name variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
"my name is %(name)s, and your name is %(name)s" % {'name': name}
```

but better to use the new `.format` method:

```
"my name is {name}, and your name is {name}".format(name=name)
```

or

```
"my name is {0}, and your name is {0}".format(name,)
```

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
"my name is {name}, and your name is {name}".format(name=name)
```